# How to create a card an ionic card with background image and overlapping text on the image

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to use the background image card example from the Ionic Docs https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#card-background but during implementation, the text doesnt overlap the background image.

```
<ion-content class="card-background-page">

  <ion-card div class="card">
    <img src="assets/img/rundmc-live.png"/>
    <div class="card-title">São Paulo</div>
    <div class="card-subtitle">41 Listings</div>
  </ion-card>

  <ion-card>
    <img src="img/card-amsterdam.png"/>
    <div class="card-title">Amsterdam</div>
    <div class="card-subtitle">64 Listings</div>
  </ion-card>

</ion-content>


page-home {

    .card-background-page {

        ion-card {
          position: relative;
          text-align: center;
        }

        .card-title {
          position: absolute;
          top: 36%;
          font-size: 2.0em;
          width: 100%;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: #fff;
        }

        .card-subtitle {
          font-size: 1.0em;
          position: absolute;
          top: 52%;
          width: 100%;
          color: #fff;
        }

      }
    }
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Where are you trying this? I can see your styles are not being applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code not seems to have a problem, however try to change your code from this

```
<ion-card div class="card">
    <img src="assets/img/rundmc-live.png"/>
    <div class="card-title">São Paulo</div>
    <div class="card-subtitle">41 Listings</div>
</ion-card>
```

to this

```
<ion-card>
    <img src="assets/img/rundmc-live.png"/>
    <div class="card-title">São Paulo</div>
    <div class="card-subtitle">41 Listings</div>
</ion-card>
```

Also check your image path whether you specifying it correctly or not.

Comment: hey,i tried to make the changes but it seems to be separating the image from the card.

Comment: surprisingly I copied your code paste and run it, it works fine actually.

Comment: @vVryan.Higz That's because your styles from `.scss` file are not loading.

Comment: @vVryan.Higz check whether you have inserted correct name in your selector or not, it can be the problem for your .scss file for not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-card>
    <ion-card-header>
      <img src="https://www.simplilearn.com/ice9/free_resources_article_thumb/Project-Scope-Management-Cover.jpg"/>
      <ion-card-subtitle>Date :  {{note.date | date: 'dd-MMM-yyyy'}}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-title>{{note.title}}</ion-card-title>
    </ion-card-header>
  
    <ion-card-content>
      {{note.content}}
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
```